# Oracle NoSQL cloud service - OperationThrottlingException when ingesting data

Tags: nosql, oracle-nosql

I got some error about my tenancy exceeded the DDL operation rate while writing some data into my NoSQL existing table. My code has a step to create the table if it doesn't exist like:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + "(id STRING) . . . etc.
```

Until now I was doing some tests and didn't have any problem. But, now I started to test a significant amount of data ingestion in sequence and got this error:

```
"oracle.nosql.driver.OperationThrottlingException: Tenant exceeded DDL operation rate limit of 4 per minute: 5"
```

This DDL is not creating any table because the table already exists, is this a bug or it works as expected?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. Only 4 DDL operations (e.g. create/drop table or index) are allowed per minute for a given tenancy. This isn't related to data ingestion, just the management of tables themselves.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/nosql-database/doc/plan-your-service.html#NCSAI-GUID-30129AB3-906B-4E71-8EFB-8E0BBCD67144

the maximum supported rate of DDL operations is 4 DDL oprations per minute